# Redirecting to another page with JavaScript and JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, redirect

I am trying to redirect the user to my log in page as soon as the registration is done, using either JSP or JavaScript.

I should mention that the registration form is calling the same page and when I say `window.location`, glassfish throws error as resource not found.

```
                                   {
    if(request.getParameter("submit")!=null)
                   {
        String uname=request.getParameter("txtusername");
        String password=request.getParameter("txtpassword");
        String mail=request.getParameter("txtemail");
        String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
        String city=request.getParameter("txtcity");
        String state=request.getParameter("txtstate");
        String country=request.getParameter("txtcountry");
        String address=request.getParameter("txtstreetaddress");
        String scity=request.getParameter("txtscity");
        String sstate=request.getParameter("txtsstate");
        String scountry=request.getParameter("txtscountry");
        String saddress=request.getParameter("txtsaddress");
        String mobile=request.getParameter("txtno");
        String gender=request.getParameter("rdbgender");
             adminClasses.user u= new adminClasses.user(0, uname, password, mail, dob, city, state, country, address, scity, sstate, scountry, saddress, mobile, gender);
              int result=adminClasses.userfunctions.addNewUser(u);
                    %>
                    <script>
                        var res=<%=result%>;
                        if(res==0)
                            {
                               window.alert("Registration Unsuccessful");
                            }
                            else
                                {
                                    window.alert("Resgistration Successful!Click Ok to Sign in");
                                    window.location="signin.jsp";
                                }
                    </script>
                    <%                  
                                           }
                              }
       catch (Exception e)
                                     {
                    out.println(e.getMessage());
                   }
```

Comment: is it possible that "signin.jsp" isn't enough information to resolve the path to the sign in page? Try the code will the full path to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do it this way:

```
...
int result = adminClasses.userfunctions.addNewUser(u);

if (result == 0) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("signupSuccess.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
...
```

It will evaluate the `result` on the server side and then, depending on the `result`, will forward to a `signupSuccess.jsp` page – i.e. the URL will stay the same, but the response will include success page's evaluated content.

Comment: can you tell me how to write the above code in a servelet instead of writing it in scriptlet ?

Comment: Do you already have a servlet? Can you provide more sources and application config?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
response.sendRedirect("signupSuccess.jsp");
```

Comment: There is no such method, only [sendRedirect](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

check your path for current page like code below ; because i think you may be writing the path wrong in

```
 window.location="signin.jsp"
```

> 

```
//    Example

//    Return the entire URL (of the current page):

    <script>

    document.write(location.href);

    </script>
//    The output of the code above is:

//    http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done like following code using java.

```
response.getWriter().write("<script> window.location="redirect_url"</script>");
```